# Index of cyclic subgroup in its normal closure

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be finite group, $x, y \in G$. Let $m=|\langle x \rangle ^G: \langle x \rangle|$, 
$n=|\langle y \rangle^G: \langle y \rangle|$. In general, we can not get that
$$(*) \ \ \ \    mn=|\langle xy \rangle^G:\langle xy \rangle|.$$

So we need additional condition to make $(*)$ hold.

If we require that $\langle x \rangle^G \cap \langle y \rangle^G=1$, does $(*)$  hold? 
If not, which conditons can make it hold?

We also interested with the case that $G$ is a infinite group.

Any reference about the normal closure of the product of two element will be welcomed.

Comment: Do you denote with $\langle x \rangle^G$ the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ containing $x$? I ask, since I'm used to the notation $\langle x^G\rangle$. If yes, then $\langle x^G\rangle\cap\langle y^G\rangle = 1$ implies (*), as you can work in the direct product of $\langle x^G\rangle$ and $\langle y^G\rangle$.

Comment: @jb: This is not true. Let's say that $<x^G>$ and $<y^G>$ are both $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. Then $m=2$, $n=2$. But $<xy^G>$ could be the whole of $<x^G><y^G>$, so the index of $<xy>$ would be $8$. This is if the group acts by conjugation on $x$ and $y$ totally separately, so the conjugacy class has $9$ elements. It could also act on them identically, for a conjugacy class of $3$ elements and an index of $2$.

Comment: @jb: Yes, $\langle x \rangle ^G $ means the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ containing $x$.

@Will: Thank you for the counterexample.

Comment: @Will: You are right, of course. I forgot about the dividing by the order of $x$ rsp. $y$. What I thought was $\langle x^G\rangle\cap\langle y^G\rangle = 1$ implies $|\langle x^G\rangle| \cdot |\langle y^G\rangle| = |\langle (xy)^G\rangle|$.

Comment: @Wei: If the orders of $x$ and $y$ are coprime and the normal closures intersect trivially, (*) holds, since $xy$ has order $|\langle x \rangle|\cdot|\langle y \rangle|$ due to **both** conditions.

Comment: @jp: You are right, the coprime order of $x$ and $y$ make (*) hold.

By the way, I don't see that $|\langle x^G \rangle||\langle y^G \rangle|=|\langle (xy)^G \rangle |$ if we only have that $\langle x^G \rangle \cap \langle y^G \rangle=1$

Comment: @Wei: $X := \langle x^G\rangle$ and $Y := \langle y^G\rangle$ are normal subgroups of $G$ with $X\cap Y = 1$, hence the (normal) subgroup $Z:=XY$ of $G$ is the direct product of $X$ and $Y$. And here my proof breaks down ...(Sorry!). A counterexample to my claim you don't understand is $(Z_2^2\times Z_2^2)\rtimes Z_3$ where $Z_3$ fixes both components $Z_2^2$ and acts nontrivially on both components, and $x$ rsp. $y$ are nontrivial elements of the first rsp. second component.

Comment: @jp: Thanks for your explanation and the example. 